# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied python django

Tags: python

Encounter problems
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:'C:\Users\may\PycharmProjects\libshopapp\templates\store'

There are relevant information for easy understanding,

```
1.
CMD:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd /d C:\Python
C:\python>

CMD passed.
```

2. All the files in the folder are all html. (The picture is as follows)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrGSw.png)

Annotation:

I really don't know how to ask why this is the case, and I hope to be patient and explain it to me. There are resources on the Internet, but I didn’t encounter it yesterday, and I cannot open it for some reason today.

How much can I explain to explain the reasons for this incident? Thank you.

```
My more information tips:
Win 10 / using python 3.8.3 /all file can not open/ Access Denied == Permission denied? / Suddenly an error popped up. Nothing like this happened before.../Django              2.2
```

Comment: You might have created the files as an administrator, which means the folder is owned by the administrator user. You can try [this guide](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-access-denied-folders-windows-10/) to see if it helps you

Comment: My 13 html can be opened from the file, but it will not be opened on the ide (compiler). I don't know how it is different from the computer win10 pop-up error.

Does win10 and ide compilers also solve the problem of permission denied? --> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied python django

Comment: sorry solved!!!!!!!
{#{% include "store" %} 權限遭拒絕室這邊出問題 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\georgiawang\\PycharmProjects\\libshopapp\\templates\\store' #}